# How to generate a Node Rest API Client based on OpenAPI Spec 3.0

Tags: node.js, rest, swagger, client, openapi

I'm a node/JS beginner, so really sorry if I missed something.

My Need is the following, I have a Swagger/OpenAPI3.0 yaml file describing an API that I need to consume. As the client will be an Node API gateway, I want this API Client code for Node.

I use the [Swagger Editor](https://editor.swagger.io/) to generate client like this :
[Screenshot of Swagger Editor](https://i.ibb.co/zNDnSbL/editor.png)

But the generated code seems dedicated to browser client and I need to refactor this to have it works properly with node.

Does it exist an alternative?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

One of the libraries which can create a TypeScript API client for Node.js *at runtime* from an OpenAPI v3 definition is called [openapi-client-axios](https://github.com/anttiviljami/openapi-client-axios).